# Importing equations with subscripts from LaTeX and solving them

Tags: import, latex, subscript

Here is a simple system of equations, copied from LaTeX:

```
g2 = ToExpression["\\beta i  s -i \\gamma _i ", TeXForm];
g3 = ToExpression["\\gamma _i i -r \\gamma _r", TeXForm];
eq = Thread[{g2, g3} == 0]
Reduce[eq, {i, r}]
```

It looks fine, but apparently Mathematica is confused by the subscripts in `eq`

```
{-i s β + λ + r Subscript[γ, r] - s Subscript[μ, s] == 0, 
 i s β - i Subscript[γ, i] - i Subscript[μ, i] == 0, 
 i Subscript[γ, i] - r Subscript[γ, r] - r Subscript[μ, r] == 0}
```

I can fix this by modifying the output above by hand

```
eq = Thread[{i s β - i γi, i γi - r γr} == 0]
Solve[eq, {i, r}]
```

Is there a more elegant way of importing equations with subscripts from LaTeX?

Comment: If you have some equation with $x_i$ then you can solve for variable $x_i$ but never solve for separate $x$ or separate $i$ because it has no mathematical sense.

Comment: I suggest _not_ importing LaTeX unless absolutely necessary. LaTeX does not encode mathematical expressions unambiguously, and LaTeX documents are written for human readers, not computers. There are some exceptional cases when this makes sense: a paper might contain large equations, and you want to avoid mistakes when typing them. You happen to have access to the paper's LaTeX sources. In these cases importing may be worthwhile, but will often require some manual pre/post processing. In this case you can transform the `Subscript` expressions to non-Subscript versions, e.g.

Comment: `... /. Subscript[a_, b_] :> 
  With[{s = StringJoin[ToString[a], ToString[b]]}, Symbol[s]]`